# Return value in angularjs service

Tags: angularjs

I have two cases of using service return value in AngularJS.

Case 1. If I am using below code its working fine

```
var SerFactProv = angular.module("SerFactProv", [])
.service('ServiceDemo', function () {
    return { fn: "1452522" };
})
.controller("sfpCtrl", function ($scope, ServiceDemo, FactoryDemo, ProviderDemo) {
    $scope.serviceResult = "This is form service : " + ServiceDemo.fn
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="SerFactProv">
    <div ng-controller="sfpCtrl">
        <p>{{serviceResult}}</p>    <br />
    </div>
</body>
```

Case 2. But if I use `.fn` in angular expression in place of controller output disappears. Please see difference of `.fn` in both codes and explain why its happening.

```
$scope.serviceResult = "This is form service : " + ServiceDemo
```

and on UI

```
<p> {{serviceResult.fn}} </p>    <br />
```

Answer (score 2):

This code

```
$scope.serviceResult = "This is form service : " + ServiceDemo
```

and HTML:

```
<p> {{serviceResult.fn}} </p>
```

don't make any sense.

`ServiceDemo` is an object. Concatenation of the string and anything is going to be string too. Arbitrary string doens't have `fn` property. Hence the undefined result.

Comment: Thank u @dfsq ....i got my point of mistake. string.fn will not work. But if i don't concatenate or use like $scope.serviceResult = ServiceDemo and <p> {{serviceResult.fn}} </p> then it will work.

Comment: If you don't concatenate and use `{{ serviceResult.fn }}` then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

just a tip, a service shouldn't be used to return an object, it's instantiated once by the core of angular and then cached so inside the service recipe you should refer with the keyword **this** as it is a constructor function:

```
 .service('ServiceDemo', function ()
{
   this.fn =  "1452522";
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your 2nd case doesn't work is because you've set the value of `$scope.serviceResult` as a string, and a string does not have a property .fn

If you set the `$scope.serviceResult` to serviceDemo (the service itself), it will work. I've used your code to make an example, this should explain the difference: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbp7jqca/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return an object from angular service use '***factory***' instead not service.

**Factory:**

```
.factory('ServiceDemo', function () {
    return { fn: "1452522" };
})
```

**Controller :**

```
.controller("sfpCtrl", function ($scope, ServiceDemo, FactoryDemo, ProviderDemo{
    $scope.serviceResult = "This is form service : " + ServiceDemo.fn
});
```

For difference between service, factory and providers see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angularjs-service-vs-provider-vs-factory)